# Scratch Org: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, bug, dmlexception, duplicate-value

I and my whole team encounter this error while inserting some data into a new Scratch Org.

`DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []`

What we are doing:
* create a new scratch org
* push source
* insert one account or one custom object (UI/Apex doesn't matter)
* insertion usually fails even though no records are in the scratch org

The problem is it's indeterministic. Tried the same steps more times on the same source, the same devhub, and sometimes it succeeds, sometimes it fails.

Moreover, another team working on a different project is not facing this issue at all.

sourceApiVersion: 45.0
sfdx-cli/7.23.1-ced0ec4940
DevHub: release 19'

**EDIT**
Source worked as expected. On 5th September it stopped working, i.e. newly created scratch org started to throw this exception even though no changes in the source were made. Even tried to create scratch org from old source that was validated through our pipeline at that time and now it's facing the same issue.

Comment: can you specify which object? is it the standard object or custom object have unique field on it?

Comment: Sometimes Account, sometimes custom object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got an answer from the support that this is known bug and will be resolved ASAP.

Answer (score -2):

Please check is there any duplicate rule active in your org.

Steps.

1. search for the duplicate rule in the setup in a classic.
2. If any deactivate that and try.

Comment: The insertion fails even on objects without any duplication rules. Also, no records are in the scratch org.

Comment: are you trying to insert in APEX or via UI

Comment: Apex/UI doesn't matter as mentioned in the question.

Comment: check is there any PB, workflow with the corresponding object